# Android Download app don't show all files from download folder

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, download, ionic-framework

I am working on a hybrid mobile application and have a problem with listing downloaded files.

I am using File Transfer to download a PDF. After the download is completed I check if the file is their with ES File Explorer and everything is ok. The PDF open without any errors.

However when I check with the build in "Download" app on my Nexus, the file is not listed.

I also tried to copy and paste or create different files in the Download folder but none was later shown in the Download app.

> How can I make it show all the files from the download folder?

I don't want to force the user to use a file manager.

Comment: Have you tried to use the download manager instead the File transfer?

Comment: No, I didn't know that their is one. I will try it but still isn't their any build in app that show a download folder content?